# How to update mono version in Xamarin.Form project in Visual Studio 2017 with Windows?

Tags: xamarin.forms, mono, monodevelop, visual-studio-app-center

I have implemented UrbanAirShip as it is given in this document. It is version 5.0.2. After implement it, I am getting following error while build in AppCenter.

> MTOUCH : error MT2101: Can't resolve the reference 'System.Void
>   ObjCRuntime.BlockLiteral::SetupBlockUnsafe(System.Delegate,System.Delegate)',
>   referenced from the method 'UrbanAirship.UAAction
>   UrbanAirship.UAAction::Action(UrbanAirship.UAActionBlock)' in
>   'Xamarin.iOS, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=84e04ff9cfb79065'

If I remove UrbanAirship or keep older version, it builds successfully.

I have contacted with AppCenter and I got following reply from them.

> You are building with mono 5_4_1, I’ve seen such errors in the past
>   when you have dependencies that require 5.8+ mono. Please try building
>   with the latest mono version in the build configuration pane. If it
>   still fails please let us know.

According to their reply, I have tried to find way where to change version of `Mono` in Build Configuration. But I didn't find in Visual Studio 2017 in Windows.

Can anybody please guide me what should I do now? If I need to upgrade Mono version, how can I update it?

[image]

Comment: The `mtouch` version is tied to the `Xamarin.iOS` version, so what version are you targeting (and which iOS version)?

Comment: @SushiHangover Thanks for quick reply. How can I check it? I think you asking SDK Version. It is 11.2. I have added screenshot of property of My project.iOS. Please suggest

Comment: Which version of VS2017 do you use? If you upgrade to the latest (which also upgrades Xamarin bits to latest), then you automatically get latest Mono.

Comment: @LexLi Is there any other way rather than upgrade full VS2017? I mean any way by NUGET or DLL or anything else?

Comment: @NanjiMange Xamarin is not .NET Core.

Comment: You can update Visual Studio Xamarin components (mono is part of the xamarin tools) using the Visual Studio Installer. Usually you get notifications from VS when an update is available but you can run the installer yourself to check for updates.